# Stored Procedure: Linked server login failure

Tags: sql-server-2005, authentication, linked-server

I'm getting "Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." from when trying to execute the code below. I've change all of the critical information, but you should get the idea.

Are some of my parameter incorrect? The local sql admin username is correct and the remote username and password is correct, but it still keeps telling me that the login failed. Any ideas?

Overall, are there other changes I need to make? Can I insert data this way?

Both DBs are sql server 2005. One is local, one is offsite and accessible via a secure vpn tunnel. I have no trouble acessing the offsite DB using SSMS using the username and password i've been provided(those i've been using in my SP).

```
-- establish the linked server and login.   
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   @server=SERVER1,@srvproduct='',@provider='SQLNCLI', @datasrc='SERVER IP ADDRESS'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin SERVER1, 'false', 'LOCAL SQL ADMIN USERNAME', 'REMOTE USERNAME', 'REMOTE PASSWORD'

insert into [SERVER1].DATABASE.dbo.INSERTTABLE(....) select fields from localtable

-- drop the linked server and login
EXEC Sp_DropServer SERVER1, 'droplogins'
```

Comment: Sounds more like a server admin question.  You might have better luck over at serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the target server is set to "Windows Authentication" only.

When you try and connect as a SQL login (specified in sp_addlinkedsrvlogin), it tries to interpret the credentials as windows and fails

This error normally occurs when @useself = 'true' for sp_addlinkedsrvlogin and the calling SQL Server is not configured for delegation. The server (not SQL server) can not pass through the Windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1) use named parameters for sp_addlinkedsrvlogin for explicitness.

2) use "go" between statements (don't execute the above as a single batch).

3) set "local sql admin username" to null - to rule that out

4) just to note, it appears that remote username/password (if specified) need to be sql-server logins, not NT Network Logins

Start with those...!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of the exact cause folks. I just moved on a created a Linked Server through the SSMS GUI.